# Crear menu de pausa SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, app, swift4

estoy creando una app para iPhone usando swift 4 y me gustaría añadirle un menú de pausa pero no sé que comandos debo utilizar para hacer que todo pare. Tengo unos timers con los que aumento la puntuación y creo elementos aleatorios, había pensado que podía detenerlos, ¿es esa la mejor opción?

```
let timer1 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(itemController.randomNumbers(firstNum: 0.5, secondNum: 1)), target: self, selector: #selector (GamePlaySceneClass.spawnItems), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

timer1.fire()
```

Los objetos están afectados por la gravedad por lo que supongo que habría que detenerla también durante la pausa.
Tras salir del menú de pausa todo debería seguir como estaba

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Estás desarrollando el juego con Sprite Kit? Si estas usando Sprite Kit esto igual te puede ayudar. *scene.view?.paused = true*

Answer (score 0):

No me queda muy clara tu pregunta.

Si lo que necesitas es parar el timer debes usar:

```
timer1.invalidate()
```

Comment: Ha comentado que también tiene objetos afectados por la gravedad, así que parar el timer no es la única opción.